# A index out of range error based on quick sort algo

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, quicksort

I'm making a visual representation tool for the quick sort algorithm, and I'm using a 1 dimensional array that is a random range of index's, filled with a random range of values. I believe the method im using to fill this array at run time is causing the issue, as ive noticed it happens about 50% of the time, but i havent been able to determine any causation/correlation between the value of the indexes, or the length of the array that would return this error:

```
canvas.create_line(masterArray[x] + 20 ,1 ,masterArray[x]+ 20, masterArray[currValue] * 1 + 100)
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'll attach the code below. My theory is that some of the values that are being filled aren't providing enough information for the line to be drawn, which is : x start, y start, x end, and y end. I cant think of any values with my current system that would not provide this information unfortunately. If anyone has any ideas id really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, W
import random
import numpy as np
randInt = random.randint(10, 100)
masterArray = [random.randint(10,75) for _ in range(randInt)]
print(randInt)
print(masterArray)

    class Example(Frame):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
    
            self.initUI()
    
        def initUI(self):
    
            self.master.title("Lines")
            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            sortedArr =quicksort(masterArray)
    
    
            canvas = Canvas(self)
            ##canvas.create_text(100,100, anchor=W , font ="Purisa", text = len(masterArray))
            for x in masterArray:
                currValue = masterArray[x]
                canvas.create_line(masterArray[x] + 20 ,1 ,masterArray[x]+ 20, masterArray[currValue] * 1 + 100)
            
            for x in sortedArr:
                currValue = sortedArr[x]
                canvas.create_line(sortedArr[x] + 20 ,500,sortedArr[x]+ 20, 500 - sortedArr[currValue] - 100 )
                ##canvas.create_line(x start,ystart ,x end, y end)
    
            canvas.create_text(125, 250, anchor=W, font="Purisa",text = "The total number of elements is: " + str(len(masterArray)))
            
            ##canvas.create_line(15, 25, 200, 25)
            ##canvas.create_line(300, 35, 300, 200, dash=(4, 2))
           ## canvas.create_line(55, 85, 155, 85, 105, 180, 55, 85)
    
            canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
    def quicksort(arr):
        elements = len(arr)
        if elements < 2:
            return arr
        current_pos = 0
    
        for i in range(1, elements):
            if arr[i] <= arr[0]:
                current_pos += 1
                temp = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[current_pos]
                arr[current_pos] = temp
        
        temp = arr[0]
        arr[0] = arr[current_pos]
        arr[current_pos] = temp
        left = quicksort(arr[0:current_pos])
        right = quicksort(arr[current_pos+1:elements])
        arr = left +[arr[current_pos]] + right
        
        
        return arr
    
    def main():
       
        root = Tk()
        ex = Example()
        root.geometry("500x500+300+300")
        root.mainloop()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I've tried playing with the random value arguments to see if anything improves, but haven't had any luck so far. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you use a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to study what an iterator is and what `for` does:

Something like this is much better:

```
for x,currValue in enumerate(masterArray):
    canvas.create_line(x + 20 ,1 ,x + 20, currValue * 1 + 100)

for x,currValue in enumerate(sortedArr):
    canvas.create_line(x + 20 ,500, x+ 20, 500 - currValue - 100 )
```

Comment: Same error happens with this code, and ill be sure to read more on iterators. Im coming from web development and am still pretty new to programming in general so i have alot to learn.

Comment: @zammystuff There is no array index in my example code so the same error is impossible, maybe on a different location, **USE A DEBUGGER**

Comment: Ive never used a debugger before, but from enabling it, and running with all the breakpoints enabled,                                                                                         
Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "C:\Users\Ethans Laptop\OneDrive\Desktop\gitRepo\visTool.py", line 34, in initUI
    canvas.create_line(masterArray[x] + 20 ,1 ,masterArray[x]+ 20, masterArray[currValue] * 1 + 100)   // is the output. same place, same error.

Comment: but im 110% sure im messing something up, and am overlooking something in what youre telling me. I will re read through everything and try and get it working.

Comment: @zammystuff Why do you think I give you a code example in the answer, not to ignore it but to try it, your debugger error still uses array indexing

Comment: Bro im so sorry. I was trying not to copy / paste the code so i could type it out and understand it more, and forgot to replace canvas.create_line(masterArray[x]  with just x. I see now why this was the issue. Thank you.